# How to stop Highcharts from recalculating ticks positions when a series is toggled?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following three y Axis set up in the chart:

```
    yAxis:[
      {
        id: 'iops'
        title:
          enabled: false
      },
      {
        id: 'latency'
        title:
          enabled: false
        opposite: true
      },
      {
        id: 'bandwidth'
        title:
          enabled: false
        opposite: true
      }
    ]
```

Each axis corresponds to one series.

When I click the series name on the legend, the series and axis are toggled.

Initially, all three axis align perfectly, all of them render the same number of labels (five in my case):

[image]

But the number of labels on axis that's toggled off and on decrement:

[image]

It seems like the label positions are recalculated somehow, how can I avoid this behaviour?

Following is a jsfiddle demo for this problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/qk3kt2t7/2/

Toggle the series and you'll see that the number of ticks on the y axis changes.

Comment: You can set alignTicks as true: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks

Comment: `alignTicks` is `true` by default.

Comment: Set tickInterval as 2m, then you keep ticks. https://jsfiddle.net/qk3kt2t7/3/

Answer (score 0):

while adding x-axis series values, hope you are adding each series separately,
while adding individual x-axis series set yAxis: 0 for 1st series, yAxis: 1 for 2nd series, yAxis: 2 for 3rd series.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in Highcharts, [#4374](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4374) - it should be fixed on the master branch: http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js

If this still doesn't work for you, could you setup jsfiddle demo?

As for workaround, set: [`ignoreHiddenSeries`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries) to false - it should help.

Comment: I've updated my question and included a jsfiddle that reproduce my problem with simplified code.

Comment: In general, ticks can be be different between initial loading and later re-rendering. This is caused by calculations in the core, where loading chart doesn't have all necessary information, which later are available. To prevent this behaviour, set fixed `yAxis.tickAmount`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/qk3kt2t7/4/